# Use Wikipedia API to Pull and Display content from an array of topics

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, wikipedia-api

I'm using the Wikipedia API to pull and display information about topics.

The code I have works fine for a single topic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Dementia&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
        var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

        // remove links as they will not work
        i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

        // remove any references
        i.find('sup').remove();

        // remove cite error
        i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

        $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));


        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });    

});

<div id="article"></div>
```

In the code above, the topic is "Dementia" shown by:

```
&page=Dementia
```

The code above works fine for a SINGLE topic, but now I'd like to modify it to loop through an ARRAY of topics, and use the "wikipedia_page_url" value from each topic in the array to determine which page to pull, and then output the content for each topic on the page:

```
<?php foreach ($resident_conditions as $resident_condition) { ?>

    <?php
    $condition_id = $resident_condition['condition_id'];
    $condition = sw::shared()->conditions->getForID($condition_id);
    $wikipedia_page_url = $condition['wikipedia_page_url'];
    ?>

    <h6><?php echo $condition['condition_name']; ?></h6>
    <div id="<?php echo $condition['condition_name']; ?>">

    <!-- This is where I want to place the content pulled from Wikipedia for each topic -->

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

The "wikipedia_page_url" value of each topic determines which page to pull from Wikipedia, demonstrated in the code below:

How can I modify the JS script above to work pull and display the content for each topic? I know I need to substitute the value of each "wikipedia_page_url" inside the script like this:

```
url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=<?php echo $condition['wikipedia_page_url']; ?>&callback=?",
```

But I dont know where to take it from here. Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Tourette_syndrome&callback=?",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
            var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);

            // remove links as they will not work
            i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

            // remove any references
            i.find('sup').remove();

            // remove cite error
            i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();

            $('#article').html($(i).find('p'));


            },
            error: function (errorMessage) {
            }
        });    
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the topics in an javascript array, then loop through them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topics = ['Dementia', 'Topic2', 'Topic3'];

    for(var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page="+topics[i]+"&callback=?",

       ... the rest of your ajax config
      });  //end of ajax
    } //end of loop
}); //end of .ready();
```